# SQL Merging 2 rows based on multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to merge 2 rows in a query based on multiple criteria (in this ex: Date and Serial #). I've tried a couple of self joins but cant seem to get it to work. I currently have data like the top 2 rows and would like to get it to the lowest row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: Row Merge]

Comment: Wich program do u use and can you add Some sampledata?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Is the picture that I posted not coming through?

Comment: I cant see it but maybe it is the app. Put the program in the tags. That way a person with experience Will find your question.

Comment: Ideally add some more details about what you've tried and where it's not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use UNION or UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation:

```
select itemtype, serialnumber, min(trantype) as trantype, changed,
       min(orderform) as orderform, . . .
group by itemtype, serialnumber, changed;
```

I don't know what the logic is for `trantype`, so I'm just guessing.